# How to solve morse code without spaces?

Tags: cipher

My friend got a note that has this morse code:

```
.--......-.----....-
```

She asked for help solving it.

It doesn't have any spaces, therefore we don't know what it means.

It is in English.

It would be really great if you were willing to help...  Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: Start at both ends.

Comment: This website might help you : https://www.dcode.fr/morse-code

Comment: There is a possibility that the last word is "test..." I wouldn't really know though.

Comment: There’s well over 500 combinations, possibly thousands, o highly doubt this is solvable

Comment: According to https://www.jbowman.com/remorse/ there are 524,288 solutions... I'm wondering if I should just give up. That's a LOT. For all I know the person who wrote the note could've been wrong and messed this whole thing up.

Comment: @surfingelephant I guess your only hope there would be to sort through them by looking for common words like ‘the’ or something. I highly doubt this is possible tbh

Comment: @surfingelephant Can you give like a context or something to the question? I'll be easier to solve than **524,288 solutions**...

Comment: It was on the back of a thank you note written after my friend gave her a birthday present.  I'm pretty sure she made a mistake.

Comment: @surfingelephant - just go back to the friend who wrote the thank you note and explain that you tried hard to interpret the text, but were unable to. Then ask what the intended message was. (And, if you get an answer, please post it here.)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a program to find all subdivisions of the morse code into english words. The minimum number of words possible is 3. There are 96 subdivisions into 3 words in my dictionary. None of them look like a solution to me.

The most plausible might be "at hero test", which would make sense if the writer of the message is telling your friend that the writer is off being tested to see if they're a hero. Another possibility is "wise no test", indicating that if the puzzle solver is wise, this puzzle should be "no test" for them, e.g. easy.

As I said, none of them look right.

```
ad saw zit  .--.. ....-.-- --....-
ads rob a   .--..... .-.----... .-
ads rod it  .--..... .-.----.. ..-
ads rode a  .--..... .-.----... .-
ads rot set .--..... .-.---- ....-
ads rots a  .--..... .-.----... .-
an haw zit  .--. .....-.-- --....-
an hey zit  .--. .....-.-- --....-
ani snob a  .--... ...-.----... .-
ani snot set    .--... ...-.---- ....-
ani snots a .--... ...-.----... .-
ani stem zit    .--... ...-.-- --....-
ani vat zit .--... ...-.-- --....-
ani veto set    .--... ...-.---- ....-
at hero bet .-- ......-.--- -....-
at hero test    .-- ......-.--- -....-
ate haw zit .--. .....-.-- --....-
ate hey zit .--. .....-.-- --....-
egis no bet .--...... -.--- -....-
egis no test    .--...... -.--- -....-
egis nod it .--...... -.----.. ..-
egis node a .--...... -.----... .-
egis none it    .--...... -.----.. ..-
egis not set    .--...... -.---- ....-
egis tam bet    .--...... -.--- -....-
egis tam test   .--...... -.--- -....-
egis tat zit    .--...... -.-- --....-
em hero bet .-- ......-.--- -....-
em hero test    .-- ......-.--- -....-
ems snob a  .--... ...-.----... .-
ems snot set    .--... ...-.---- ....-
ems snots a .--... ...-.----... .-
ems stem zit    .--... ...-.-- --....-
ems vat zit .--... ...-.-- --....-
ems veto set    .--... ...-.---- ....-
pee snob a  .--... ...-.----... .-
pee snot set    .--... ...-.---- ....-
pee snots a .--... ...-.----... .-
pee stem zit    .--... ...-.-- --....-
pee vat zit .--... ...-.-- --....-
pee veto set    .--... ...-.---- ....-
pees no bet .--...... -.--- -....-
pees no test    .--...... -.--- -....-
pees nod it .--...... -.----.. ..-
pees node a .--...... -.----... .-
pees none it    .--...... -.----.. ..-
pees not set    .--...... -.---- ....-
pees tam bet    .--...... -.--- -....-
pees tam test   .--...... -.--- -....-
pees tat zit    .--...... -.-- --....-
peeve ode a .--......-. ----... .-
peeve one it    .--......-. ----.. ..-
peeve to set    .--......-. ---- ....-
pi snob a   .--... ...-.----... .-
pi snot set .--... ...-.---- ....-
pi snots a  .--... ...-.----... .-
pi stem zit .--... ...-.-- --....-
pi vat zit  .--... ...-.-- --....-
pi veto set .--... ...-.---- ....-
pie erode a .--.... ..-.----... .-
pie fob a   .--.... ..-.----... .-
pie into set    .--.... ..-.---- ....-
pie item zit    .--.... ..-.-- --....-
pis no bet  .--...... -.--- -....-
pis no test .--...... -.--- -....-
pis nod it  .--...... -.----.. ..-
pis node a  .--...... -.----... .-
pis none it .--...... -.----.. ..-
pis not set .--...... -.---- ....-
pis tam bet .--...... -.--- -....-
pis tam test    .--...... -.--- -....-
pis tat zit .--...... -.-- --....-
we haw zit  .--. .....-.-- --....-
we hey zit  .--. .....-.-- --....-
wee saw zit .--.. ....-.-- --....-
wees rob a  .--..... .-.----... .-
wees rod it .--..... .-.----.. ..-
wees rode a .--..... .-.----... .-
wees rot set    .--..... .-.---- ....-
wees rots a .--..... .-.----... .-
whit am bet .--......- .--- -....-
whit am test    .--......- .--- -....-
whit at zit .--......- .-- --....-
whit em zit .--......- .-- --....-
white ode a .--......-. ----... .-
white one it    .--......-. ----.. ..-
white to set    .--......-. ---- ....-
wise no bet .--...... -.--- -....-
wise no test    .--...... -.--- -....-
wise nod it .--...... -.----.. ..-
wise node a .--...... -.----... .-
wise none it    .--...... -.----.. ..-
wise not set    .--...... -.---- ....-
wise tam bet    .--...... -.--- -....-
wise tam test   .--...... -.--- -....-
wise tat zit    .--...... -.-- --....-
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that either the person originally writing the code, or your friend when copying it to post here, made a mistake, leaving out a run of two dashes and a dot in the middle, and the original message was intended to read:

> white mamba

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to issacg's answer, I used a (probably) larger dictionary and examined a lot of divisions. Here are some divisions making some sense (not a lot of sense I would say) to me:

```
ez hk mba
ez saw gia
ez sent mba
we sino test
white to set
white to sa
wise yt test
wise tw gia
we site on eu
we site on ia
we site on st
we see no test
we see no bet
we see none ea
we seen one ea
we seek mba
an hr to est
an hr to sa
an hr to set
a beer on eu
a beer to est
a beer to sa
a beer to set
wise note v
wise note eu
at hero test
at hero bet
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an online tool I got the following phrase:

> WHITE NOTES

Comment: Hi Stratos - how does this work? As it is written the last symbol of the cipher is a dash. Your translation here ends in an S which is dot-dot-dot - no dash in sight!

Comment: @Stiv There is an online option to decrypt morse code that has no seperators and I selected the integration of common words from dictionary.

Comment: But is it an anagram or something? Because that message (which ends in a dash) cannot possibly end in an S (which ends in a dot)...

Comment: @StivI really don''t know for sure but this is the best I can do and I thought to give it a try.

Comment: "I don't know. I just work here."

Comment: @Lanny Strack In Greek we sometimes use the dot and the dash at the end of the message to denote that the message has ended and there is nothing more. Maybe that's the case here too.